# How can I use Glib.timeout_add() function to wait a keypress event

Tags: python-3.x, gtk3, glib

I am trying to create a test application. The application should list images in a directory, show the first one on screen, takes a keyboard response and show the second image, takes response, and does this for each image.

I created a glade file and I am using it to create the interface within the `RavensAPM` class. There is a `Gtk.Window` in the glade file which contains a single `Gtk.Box` which in turn contains a single `Gtk.Image`. I use `run_ravens_apm()` function to list images and feed images one by one to `RavensAPM` class. Within the `RavensAPM` class I update image and using `show_all()` present everything.

At this point I want the app to wait for a keypress event from keys [1-8] and keypad keys [1-8].

I examined the usage of `GLib.timeout_add()` function but I cannot be able to get the desired behavior out of it. At the moment, the `for` loop within the `run_ravens_apm()` calls `RavensAPM` at the same time and create as many windows as the number of images, without waiting a keyboard signal/event.

I tried to put `GLib.timeout_add()` within the class's `__call__()` method and use the instance of the class as a function, but it also did not work.

What am I doing wrong?

```
class RavensAPM:
    def __init__(self, test_image):
        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file('glade/window_ravens_apm.glade')
        self.window = self.builder.get_object('window_ravens_apm')
        self.window.fullscreen()
        self.window.connect('key-release-event', self.on_event_after)

        window_height = 1080

        self.pixbuf_file = \
            GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_scale(test_image,
                                                    -1,
                                                    window_height,
                                                    True)
        self.image = self.builder.get_object('ravens_apm_image')
        self.image.set_from_pixbuf(self.pixbuf_file)
        self.window.show_all()

    def on_event_after(self, widget, event):
        keys = [i for i in range(49, 57)] + [i for i in range(65457, 65465)]
        key_value = event.keyval
        if keys in key_value:
            self.window.destroy()
            return False

    def __call__(self):
        self.on_event_after()
        return True


def run_ravens_apm():
    # List the contents of img/ravens_apm
    # Use a loop to run RavensAPM for the length of images
    interval_ms = 200
    img_directory = 'img/ravens_apm'
    img_files = os.listdir(img_directory)
    img_files.sort()
    img_files = img_files[:2]
    nr_images = len(img_files)

    for i in range(nr_images):
        img_file = os.path.join(img_directory, img_files[i])
        ravens = RavensAPM(img_file)
        GLib.timeout_add(interval_ms, ravens)
        print('GLib.timeout_add must wait for Gdk.EventKey event')
        print(datetime.datetime.now())
```

Contents of the glade file is a follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.18.3 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.12"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window_ravens_apm">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <signal name="key-press-event" handler="on_windows_ravens_apm_key_press_event" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkViewport" id="viewport1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkBox" id="box1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkImage" id="ravens_apm_image">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="stock">gtk-missing-image</property>
                <signal name="key-press-event" handler="on_ravens_apm_keypress" swapped="no"/>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">True</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">0</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

Comment: Off the top, I am going to say you come from a programming language other than Gtk and Python. Have a look at http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/builder.html to get started.

Comment: That's not what `timeout_add` does. Read up on GLib's main event loop, your key press event handler should basically just swap images when you receive a key press.

Comment: Thank you @nemequ. After I read your comment I realized what I have to do. By just using a simple callback method I created the script I want.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need a longer answer I am posting my solution here. It is simple. Now I know that I should have never used `Glib.timeout_add()` function in the first place.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import gi
import os
import random
from gi.repository import Gtk
from gi.repository import GdkPixbuf
# from gi.repository import Gdk
# from gi.repository import GLib
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')


FAKING_FIRTS = None
WINDOW_HEIGHT = 1080


class RavensAPM:
    def __init__(self, img_list, window_height):
        self.img_list = img_list
        self.window_height = window_height

        self.builder = Gtk.Builder()
        self.builder.add_from_file('glade/window_ravens_apm.glade')

        self.window = self.builder.get_object('window_ravens_apm')
        self.window.connect('key-release-event', self.on_key_released)
        self.window.fullscreen()

        self.ravens_image = self.builder.get_object('ravens_apm_image')
        self.pixbuf_file = \
            GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_scale(self.img_list[-1],
                                                    -1,
                                                    self.window_height,
                                                    True)
        self.ravens_image.set_from_pixbuf(self.pixbuf_file)

        self.window.show_all()

    def on_key_released(self, widget, event):
        key_value = event.keyval
        keys_list = list(range(49, 57)) + list(range(65429, 65436))
        if key_value in keys_list:
            # TODO
            # Do stg to save the keyvalue somewhere
            self.img_list.pop()
            self.pixbuf_file = \
                GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf.new_from_file_at_scale(self.img_list[-1],
                                                        -1,
                                                        self.window_height,
                                                        True)
            self.ravens_image = self.builder.get_object('ravens_apm_image')
            self.ravens_image.set_from_pixbuf(self.pixbuf_file)


def run_ravens_apm():
    img_directory = 'img/ravens_apm'
    img_files = os.listdir(img_directory)
    img_files.sort(reverse=True)
    img_files = [os.path.join(img_directory, i) for i in img_files]
    RavensAPM(img_files, WINDOW_HEIGHT)
```

Here is the Glade file I used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.18.3 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.12"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window_ravens_apm">
    <property name="can_focus">False</property>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkViewport" id="viewport1">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can_focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkBox" id="box1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can_focus">False</property>
            <property name="orientation">vertical</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkImage" id="ravens_apm_image">
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can_focus">False</property>
                <property name="stock">gtk-missing-image</property>
                <signal name="key-press-event" handler="on_ravens_apm_keypress" swapped="no"/>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="expand">True</property>
                <property name="fill">True</property>
                <property name="position">0</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
          </object>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```